# Azure CDN Custom Domain Not Working

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn

I am trying to setup a CDN. I tested the the CDN and it works great using this script

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://az849200.vo.msecnd.net/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#date").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
            $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
            $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
            $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="date" name="date" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the issue is when I change:

```
<script src="http://az849200.vo.msecnd.net/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

to my custom domain

```
<script src="http://cdn.fingerscrossederie.com/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

As you can see from this screenshot I created a CNAME with Network Solutions and it was accepted by Azure.

[image: CDN Screenshot]

I was reading this article and it says that there might be a delay when creating a custom domain but it has been 13 hours since I created the custom domain.

[Create Custom Domain](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain/)

CNAME Screenshot

[image: CNAME Screenshot]

I am not sure where to go from here.

Dan

Comment: That screenshot shows the azure portal view of the world, not your DNS services view of the world.  An `nslookup` check of your domain didn't
 show any CNAME records.  Possibly you have an issue with Network Solutions.

Comment: I setup it up in Network Solutions exactly how the instructions say in Azure. I edited the question to show the CNAME Screenshot

Comment: Looks like you have the verify cname, but not the actual cname. ( I.e point `cdn.fingerscrossederie.com` to `az849200.vo.msecnd.net`)

Comment: The documentation says to use cdnverify in three CNAME

Comment: Well, if `cdn.fingerscrossederie.com` doesn't point to the Azure CDN domain, how is it going to resolve to the correct address?

Answer (score 0):

You're really close.

```
cdn.fingerscrossederie.com
```

should be a dns CNAME record and point to

```
az849200.vo.msecnd.net
```

You should configure this in your own hosting/domain name manager(network solutions).

Tip: Set a short TTL in the beginning, so if you make a mistake you won't have to wait for hours until the TTL has expired. A TTL of 7200 is quite long if you make a mistake.

Checking / verifying goes like so:

Command:

```
dig cdn.fingerscrossederie.com
```

Output to look for(this looks correct btw):

> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>
> cdn.fingerscrossederie.com. 7199 IN   CNAME   az849200.vo.msecnd.net.
>
> az849200.vo.msecnd.net.   3599    IN  CNAME   cs3.wpc.v0cdn.net.
>
> cs3.wpc.v0cdn.net.    3599    IN  A   93.184.221.200

Once you've verified you're getting the right CNAME back, it's time to verify your setup works. This can be done with two simple curl commands and compare the headers:

Command:

```
$ curl -I http://cdn.fingerscrossederie.com/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.js
```

Output:

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Date: Fri, 08 Jan 11:37:55 GMT
>
> Server: ECAcc (ams/48AE)
>
> Content-Length: 345

And the other one:

Command(this should be the cdn url - the one that you cnamed to):

```
$ curl -I http://az849200.vo.msecnd.netjquery/jquery.maskedinput.js -H "Host: cdn.fingerscrossederie.com"
```

Output:

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Date: Fri, 08 Jan 11:39:25 GMT
>
> Server: ECAcc (ams/48AE)
>
> Content-Length: 345

Seeing as you're getting 404's on both ends this means two things:

1. Your cdn.yourdomain.com CNAME is working
2. Your origin url isn't setup properly, so the cdn can't find the actual file that you're looking to fetch.

Hope this helps